# how to convert parent object with child object list into xml file using c#?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I have a parent table Class and a child table Subject. I have created objects of these classes and child objects added as a list in parent class. Now I want to read a parent table data using linq and convert it into an xml file using xml serialization.

Here's my code

```
ClassMaster cls = new ClassMaster();List<ClassMaster> clsList =  
  cls.FindAll().Where(t => t.ClassSymbol == "I").ToList();

var serializer1 = new XmlSerializer(cls.FindAll().GetType());
ClassMaster cls = new ClassMaster();
var stringwriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(cls.GetType());
serializer.Serialize(stringwriter, cls);
```

But its throwing a exception in line 3

> "Cannot serialize member 'School.Objects.ClassMaster.classSubjectList'
>   of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[[School.Objects.ClassWiseSubject,
>   School.Objects, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]]'"

```
public class ClassMaster : GenericRepository<ClassMaster>
{
  public virtual int ClassId { get; set; }
  public virtual string ClassSymbol { get; set; }
  public virtual string ClassName { get; set; }
  public virtual IList<ClassWiseSubject> classSubjectList { get; set; }
}

public class ClassWiseSubject : GenericRepository<ClassWiseSubject>
{
  public virtual int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual int ParentID { get; set; }
  public virtual int SerialNo { get; set; }
  public virtual string SubjectCode { get; set; }
}
```

HBM config file :

```
  <class name="ClassMaster" table="tbl_ClassMaster">
    <id name="ClassId" column="ClassId" type="int">
      <generator class="identity"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="ClassSymbol"  column="ClassSymbol" type="string"/>
    <property name="ClassName"  column="ClassName" type="string"/>
    <list name="classSubjectList" cascade="all" lazy ="false">
      <key column="ParentID"/>
      <index column="SerialNo"/>
      <one-to-many class="ClassWiseSubject"/>
    </list>
  </class>

  <class name="SubjectMaster" table="tbl_SubjectMaster">
    <id name="SubjectId" column="SubjectId" type="int">
      <generator class="identity"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="SubjectCode"  column="SubjectCode" type="string"/>
    <property name="SubjectName"  column="SubjectName" type="string"/>
  </class>
```

Thanks
Surajit

Comment: [Edit] and fix your formatting.  Don't try to put code in a numbered list, that won't work.

Answer (score 1):

`XmlSerializer` doesn't support `IList<T>` interface. You have several options:

- change type from `IList<T>` to concrete class (e.g. `List<T>`);
- use `DataContractSerializer` instead of `XmlSerializer`;
- implement `IXmlSerializable`;
- create fake property of type `List<T>` for `XmlSerializer` reading and writing to `classSubjectList` and mark `classSubjectList` with `[XmlIgnore]` attribute.

Comment: Hi ,  Thanks for the reply its working .Now I have used DataContractSerializer .

Comment: Please mark answer as accepted for others to see it's solved. Click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in